# Using the result of an outer query as part of a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in postgres that looks like this

```
SELECT events.startDate, managers.id, manager.name, manager.goneDate
FROM mentions, managers, events, categories
WHERE 
managers.id = mentions.manager_id AND
events.id = mentions.event_id AND
categories.id = events.category_id
```

I also have a query that does some division that I need to join to it using the result of the events.startDate for each row, that query looks like this...

```
SELECT round((cast count(manager.id)
FROM mentions, managers, events
WHERE 
managers.id = mentions.manager_id AND
events.id = mentions.event_id AND
events.eventdate >= (to_date('2012-08-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - INTERVAL '90 days') AND 
events.eventdate <= '2012-08-18'
AND mentions.manager_id = 1
group by managers.id) as decimal)
/
(SELECT count(managers.id)
 FROM mentions, managers, events
 WHERE 
managers.id = mentions.manager_id AND
events.id = mentions.event_id AND
events.eventdate >= (to_date('2012-08-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - INTERVAL '90 days') AND 
events.eventdate <= '2012-08-18'
AND mentions.manager_id = 1
group by managers.id) 
* 100), 2) as "result"
```

So essentially I need to join the result on to the "results" of my first query and instead of the hard coded date (2012-08-18) on the 2nd query I need to use the events.startDate for each row of the 1st query.

Comment: don't have time but you can try CTE : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html

Comment: lol at goneDate

Comment: Please stop using commas in the FROM clause and use explicit join syntax

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what you mean, the upper query isn't grouped by `managers.id`, but the lower 2 are. Why compare `events.startDate` >= `events.eventdate - 90 days` how can the start date differ from the event date...

Comment: I ended up figuring this out, I needed to use correlated queries, and then index a couple of the columns in the referenced query to speed it up.